# Как передать переменную из одного скрипта в другой Godot 4?

Tags: godot, gdscript

У меня есть скрипт сцены "main_menu.gd", я передаю его в скрипт сцены "levels.gd".

Скрипт `main_menu.gd`:

```
@export var music_menu_pos = 0.0
```

Скрипт `levels.gd`:

```
@onready var music_pos = get_node("res://scripts/main_menu.gd").music_menu_pos
```

**Проблема**: Выводит ошибку при нажатии на кнопку перехода в сцену `levels.gd` из `main_menu.gd`:

> Invalid get index 'music_menu_pos' (on base: 'null instance')

Я не понимаю почему переменная пустая, если в функции сцены "main_menu.gd" при нажатии на кнопку перехода в сцену "levels.gd" я проверил переменную `music_menu_pos` и она выдает не пустое значение, а позицию саундтрека.
Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема не в том что переменная `music_menu_pos` пустая, а то что вы пытаетесь её получить у пустого объекта.

Это можно решить с помощью `<ОБЪЕКТ>.get("<ИМЯ ПОЛЯ>")`:

```
...

var n = $<АБСОЛЮТНЫЙ ПУТЬ К ОБЪЕКТУ>
    
n.get("music_menu_pos")  # Или другое имя, какое вам надо

...
```

Очень надеюсь что поможет (сам только изучаю Godot).

Comment: И ещё я хотел спросить у вас есть аккаунт на [GitHub](https://github.com)?